# Java compiler warning for changing a method argument variable in method body

Tags: eclipse, compiler-warnings

```
public class InsertionSort {
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] array) {
        for (int indexOfNextToInsert = 1; indexOfNextToInsert < array.length; indexOfNextToInsert++) {
            // array from array[0] to array[indexOfNextItemToReposition - 1] is sorted
            // now insert array item at "indexOfNextItemToReposition" into
            // the sorted left side of array
            insert(array, indexOfNextToInsert);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void insert(T[] array, int indexOfNextToInsert) {
        T nextValue = array[indexOfNextToInsert];
        while (indexOfNextToInsert > 0 && nextValue.compareTo(array[indexOfNextToInsert - 1]) < 0) {
            array[indexOfNextToInsert] = array[indexOfNextToInsert - 1];
            indexOfNextToInsert--; //<-- I am getting an warning here in eclipse
        }
        array[indexOfNextToInsert] = nextValue;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't reassign method parameters. Assignment to a parameter could be confused with an attempt to use it as an [output parameter](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=37). Further discussion: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/remove-assignments-to-parameters.